# modify a list of columns in order to pass it to include or exclude the columns from dataframe

Tags: pandas, list

I would like to do some automation by one machine learning project. I have following columns in my df.

```
df_col = ["Feature1", "Feature2", "Feature3", "Feature4", "Feature5"]
```

I would like to generate all combinations of column names and then run the model in a loop with all combinations, in order to eliminate not useful features from my model.
I have done all combinations in a list, but they have a wrong format in order to be passed with

```
df = df.drop([all_combinations], axis=1).
```

The code for generation of the combination of column names (features) in my df:

```
df_col = ["Feature1", "Feature2", "Feature3", "Feature4", "Feature5"]

import itertools  
all_combinations = []
for r in range(len(df_col) + 1):
    combinations_object = itertools.combinations(df_col, r)
    combinations_list = list(combinations_object)
    all_combinations += combinations_list
all_combinations
```

The format which is given is is not accepted by the drop function of features in pandas.

[image]

Is there any way, how to generate all the combination of features in df and then pass the list of these with?

```
df = df.drop([all_combinations], axis=1).
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what data type you want, but if you're after having single quotation marks within a string you can try this:

```py
df_col = ["Feature1", "Feature2", "Feature3", "Feature4", "Feature5"]

# Saved as "'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3', 'Feature4', 'Feature5'"
str_list = ", ".join([f"'{val}'" for val in df_col]) 

print(str_list)
```

**Output:**

```
'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3', 'Feature4', 'Feature5'
```

Comment: but it is not a list anymore.  When i run x[0] it shows the error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3', 'Feature4', 'Feature5'` is just the printed result of the string `"'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3', 'Feature4', 'Feature5'"` and not a data structure and cannot be stored in itself.

If you explain some more about your use case I'll be happy to help!

Comment: I would like to do some automation by ML. I have X columns in my df. I would like to generate all combinations of column names and then run the model in  a loop with all combinations, in order to eliminate not useful features from my model. I have done all combinations in a list, but they have a wrong format in order to be passed with df1 = df1.drop([all_combination], axis=1). The format which is given is: [(), ('Feature1'), ('Feature2'), ('Feature1', 'Feature2')] and this is not accepted by the drop function in pandas

Answer (score 0):

Now answering the edited question. You need to iterate through all your combinations and make a selection from the dataframe for each combination:

```py
for combination in all_combinations:
  # Alternative 1
  # Keeps all BUT the columns in combination
  df_subset = df.drop(list(combination), axis=1) # combination is tuple, drop only accepts lists
  
  # Alternative 2
  # Keeps all the columns in combination.
  # I think this is more useful as you know which features you have used in the subset.
  # df_subset = df.filter(items=combination)

  ### Do ML stuff on df_subset
```

Comment: I schwitched the PC's / accounts. Thank you for your answer. Yea, the same i already tried, but the problem is, that the format of "all_combinations" - see the printscreen above, does not work with df.drop. Maybe i should show an example on some online dataset. The Python shown an error: "Column names are not in df" - because of wrong format of the list for such purposes.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that you're passing `all_combinations` directly into `df.drop`? This is not possible. As I've said it will work (at least syntactically) to pass an element of `all_combinations` at the time. E.g `df.drop(list(('Feature1', 'Feature2')), axis=1)` or `df.filter(items=('Feature1', 'Feature2'))`. Assuming that all elements are column names in the dataframe.

Comment: I solved the problem. Not the column names should be passed, but the indices of columns. And then drop columns by indices.